# PHP page teleporting

Tags: php, redirect, include

I'm trying to make a special parameter that when it's accessed it opens another php file on my webserver , Here's what I've been trying to do

```
<?php
$id = ($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : $_POST['id'];
switch($id)
{
case 'account':
require 'pages/cp.php';
break;
}
?>
```

So when the user authenticates to , let's say : http://www.test.com/?id=account , It should automatically authorize the user to the file cp.php .

Problem is that it doesn't redirect , It just remains on the index.php file .

Note : The above PHP code exists in the index.php !

Thanks!

Comment: does cp.php contain a redirect (`header()`)  call?

Comment: Have you tried to echo `$id` variable before switch-case? What does it show?

Comment: @andrew , No the cp.php doesn't have a header call as I have used it before without header() calls and it worked .

Comment: `require` doesn't send the browser to another page, it just imports the content from it and outputs it to the current page (index). you need `header` for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: I don't use require to redirect , I use this echo'<script language="JavaScript">window.open("?id=account", "_self")</script>';

Comment: @AhmedMagdy well then I suggest you edit the question and explain the situation more clearly

Comment: Found a way around that , Thanks for your patience and help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

require() just like require_once() or include() will actually just include the file into the current script... it basically puts the source from 'pages/cp.php' right there - where you include it.

If you want to redirect the user to a new URL/Link/File you should use header:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
```

Just make sure you have no output (not even some HTML in the php file, or a whitespace outside of  (pretty common mistake)) at all before you set the header or it will fail.

If you need output before you send header, make sure to use ob_start(); and ob_flush() - google, stackoverflow or the php-manual will help you there.